# JSFiddle "Blocked loading mixed active content"

Tags: javascript, http, https, jsfiddle

I'm trying to load some old fiddles that worked in the past (say 6-months ago), and now external libraries are not loading due to not being https links:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js”
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css”
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js”
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css”
TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function
```

The last error is clearly because the libraries are not loading.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/2ydhrLmx/3/

Is this a browser configuration issue? Work firewall? I've tried it in updated chrome and firefox.

If I fix the links, the fiddles work. But why should I need to do that with all of my old fiddles?

Comment: You just need to change your http for https....

Comment: Yes, but why should I have to go back and change all of my old fiddles. Many of them are linked to in SO questions. Now they won't display properly. Why is this happening now?

Comment: Change on the jsfiddle policies....they estarted doing this like, mmm, 9 months ago

Comment: Oh golly. There are probably a zillion fiddles out there that will not work now. They should really make a button to automagically update the links.

Comment: Yeah...doing something like that shouldn't be a problem...maybe they are lazy :)

Comment: I updated my external resource link, and I'm still getting blocked content. I have jquery-ui checked in the new gear-javascript resources. If I uncheck it, then it can't find the `$(sortable)` widget. https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/2ydhrLmx/8/

Comment: Fixed https://jsfiddle.net/2ydhrLmx/12/

Comment: Cool! I'm not seeing where you loaded jquery-ui (edit: I see now) ? I did this: https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/2ydhrLmx/

Comment: It's funny because, the jquery-ui version included by jsfiddle is on http, so, it never works....I just remove that dependency and added the https version as a external resource...yours doesn´t works because you have included 2 versions of jquery....for more details from Chrome right click on the result frame and choose the option "frame source code" or something like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

jsfiddle seems to have migrated to fiddle.jshell.net. So you need to:

1. Change your URL from `jsfiddle.net/yourname/*` to `fiddle.jshell.net/yourname/*`.
2. Select your libraries with the gear, the will load properly. But it's tricky, because only some versions of jQuery have associated jQuery UI libraries, and not all work.

If all goes well, you original fiddle will work without having to load eternal https libraries.

Here is the example I gave in the question. Only changes are 1) changed URL and 2) selected libraries under gear.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/abalter/2ydhrLmx/